# Avoiding value restriction error for generic use of function that returns two functions

Tags: f#, type-inference, fparsec

I want to use the FParsec createParserForwardedToRef function with a generic Expr union, like this:

```
type Expr<'Term> =
        | Unary of Operator * Expr<'Term>
        | Binary of Operator * Expr<'Term> * Expr<'Term>
        | Ternary of Operator * Expr<'Term> * Expr<'Term> * Expr<'Term>
        | Term of 'Term
let expr, exprR = createParserForwardedToRef<Expr<'T>,unit>()
```

I can't get rid of the value restriction error. I can't turn `expr` into a CLR function, much less `exprR`.

How would I normally deal with this situation?

Comment: Can you post a complete example? Per your example, you need `Parser<Expr<'T>,unit>` instead of `Expr<'T>,unit`.

Comment: @pad Sorry, I can't quite figure out which code would be relevant. I hope my edit clarifies things. Are you talking about the type arguments to `createParserForwardedToRef`? Because that seems to take just the result type and the state type, not the whole `Parser` type.

Comment: A typical trick for avoiding "value restriction" error with FParsec is: `type Parser<'t> = Parser<'t, UserState>`. Please give it a try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tricky bit is the generic `Expr<'T>`. You can make a function that returns `expr` parser, and let subsequent use of parsers determine a specific type of `Expr<'T>`:

```
let expr() =
    // initially exprRef holds a reference to a dummy parser 
    let expr, exprRef = createParserForwardedToRef()

    // create other union-case parsers as inner or outer functions
    let unary() = ...
    let binary = ...
    let ternary() = ...
    let term() = ...

    // replace dummy parser reference in exprRef
    do exprRef := choice [unary(); binary(); ternary(); term()]
    expr
```

You could also pass primitive parsers such as `term` as arguments to `expr` function. In this case, type of `expr` depends on different kinds of parsers passed on e.g. `pstring`, `pfloat`.

FParsec tutorial has a section on [F# value restriction](http://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/tutorial.html#fs-value-restriction) which might also be helpful.